# Java double value not exact

Tags: java, primitive-types

The loop

```
double d=1.00d;
for (int i=0; i<=3; i++)
    System.out.println(d+i*0.2);
```

is giving 1.2000001 (don't recall how many 0-s after the decimal, isn't regularly happening) sometimes.

What's the best way to get aroun this glitch? i'd ecpect to have 1.20 when `i` hits 1.

TIA

Comment: Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) if you need precision.

Comment: BigDecimal seems too "costly" for a this much

Comment: If you need virtually infinite precision - use BigDecimal. `double` (as well as `float`) are inherently imprecise.